# Convert yymmdd to datetime using ssis derived column

Tags: ssis, datatypes, type-conversion

Below are the strings representing date of birth (yymmdd). I want to convert it into datetime format and load into a database using ssis. How can I do it? In my derived column I have `(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],1,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],3,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],5,2))`, but it's not working.

- 470324
- 470324
- 470209
- 101
- 0

Comment: In newer versions (2008 and up), you should use [(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2, «scale»)](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/DevinKnight/ssis/1387/ssis-to-sql-server-data-type-translations) which is datetime2 equivalent in SQL Server. Also refer to [Why You Should Never Use DATETIME Again!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdnsoldevs/archive/2011/06/22/why-you-should-never-use-datetime-again.aspx).

Comment: @kin can you show me how to do it.. I tried but seems like I am not getting it right.

Comment: What is the appropriate action to take when the data is insufficient? In your sample, `101` and `0` won't convert to a valid date as the string is too short but there could also be bad values recorded - 30 days in February, etc

Comment: I m using this to handle 0 and six digits string Date of birth,.......................................................[Drv DOB] == "0" ? (DT_DATE)0 : (DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING("20" + [Drv DOB],1,2) + SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],3,2) + SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],5,2))...........I see what you saying..

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74584/multiple-conditions-in-a-derived-column-ssis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  have done something like this and it works.

```
([Drv DOB] == "0") || ([Drv DOB] == "101") ? NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) : (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],1,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],3,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],5,2))
```

Answer (score 7):

### Data Flow

Here's the general approach I'd take to solving your problem.

[image: data flow]

I started with your source data and added some other conditions - a NULL as well as a 14 and 15 year to ensure my logic later is correct.

```
SELECT 
    D.DrvDOB
FROM
(
    VALUES
    ('470324')
,   ('470324')
,   ('470209')
,   ('140209')
,   ('150209')
,   ('101')
,   ('0')
,   (NULL)
) D(DrvDOB);
```

This is going to seem like a lot of work, but for me, this is the most maintainable approach. If something's wrong, I can simply inspect between the derived columns and find the failing bit of logic. Many people mistakenly believe the amount of components on a data flow decrease the processing time. The reverse case can actually be true, see the sqlblog post at the end for more details.

Create a column called `IsValidLength` This is going to provide us a boolean to tell us whether we even need to try and parse the year, month and day from the string. I'm ensuring we don't have a NULL value and that the length is 6. Otherwise, we're going to flag as invalid

```
!IsNull([DrvDOB]) && LEN([DrvDOB]) == 6
```

I then am going to generate 3 more string columns (der_Year, der_Month, der_Day) with the parsed year, month and day. Otherwise, I'm going to use 00 as my value. Again, I only attempt to parse the string if it's valid.

```
(IsValidLength) ? SUBSTRING([DrvDOB], 1, 2) : "00"
(IsValidLength) ? SUBSTRING([DrvDOB], 3, 2) : "00"
(IsValidLength) ? SUBSTRING([DrvDOB], 5, 2) : "00"
```

Now comes the actual fun part, determining the actual year. Since your field is called date of birth, I'm assuming there are no future dated records - my apologies if you have psychic data. I took the route SQL Server, .NET library and COM use and have a prescribed year to use as the marker between what gets tagged as 19XX vs 20XX. I create an SSIS Variable called `TwoDigitYearCutoff` and assign it a value of 2014. In short, any years that are parsed from 00 to 14 will be tagged with the 21st century, while the rest are left in the 20th century. Adjust this value as needed.

Back in my data flow, I create yet another column, this one der_ActualYear which will be the 4 digit year.

```
(@[User::TwoDigitYearCutoff] / 100 
- ((DT_I4)der_Year > @[User::TwoDigitYearCutoff] % 100 ? 1 : 0)) 
* 100 + (DT_I4)der_Year
```

At this point, we know the full year, the month and day along with whether this data is any good. The final piece then is to put it all together and make it an actual Date. I build out a YYYY-MM-DD string and cast that as a date. Otherwise, I cast NULL as a date (to get my metadata consistent)

```
(IsValidLength) ? (DT_DATE) ((DT_WSTR, 4) [der_ActualYear] 
+ "-" + [der_Month] + "-" + [der_Day]) : NULL(DT_DATE)
```

You can now wire der_DrvDOB into your target destination knowing that you have a valid date or a NULL.

### Results

As expected, valid dates or null

[image: Results]

### Biml

Biml, the Business Intelligence Markup Language, describes the platform for business intelligence. Here, we're going to use it to describe the ETL. [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com), is a free add on for Visual Studio/BIDS/SSDT that addresses a host of shortcomings with it. Specifically, we're going to use the ability to transform a Biml file describing ETL into an SSIS package. This has the added benefit of provding you a mechanism for being able to generate exactly the solution I'm describing versus clicking through many tedious dialogue boxes.

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <!-- 74383 -->
    <Connections>
        <OleDbConnection ConnectionString="Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=localhost\dev2014;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=tempdb" Name="CM_OLE" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="dba_74383" ConstraintMode="Linear">
            <Variables>

                <Variable DataType="Int32" Name="TwoDigitYearCutoff">2014<Annotations>
                    <Annotation AnnotationType="Description">Use the two digit year cutoff to specify an integer from 1753 to 9999 that represents the cutoff year for interpreting two-digit years as four-digit years</Annotation>
                </Annotations>
            </Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT Make Dates">
                    <Transformations>
                        <OleDbSource ConnectionName="CM_OLE" Name="OLE_SRC Gen data">
                            <DirectInput>SELECT 
    D.DrvDOB
FROM
(
    VALUES
    ('470324')
,   ('470324')
,   ('470209')
,   ('140209')
,   ('150209')
,   ('101')
,   ('0')
,   (NULL)
) D(DrvDOB);</DirectInput>
                        </OleDbSource>
                        <!--
                            Test whether we have minimally valid data
                        -->
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER IsValidLength">
                            <Columns>
                                <Column Name="IsValidLength" DataType="Boolean"><![CDATA[!IsNull([DrvDOB]) && LEN([DrvDOB]) == 6 ]]></Column>
                            </Columns>
                        </DerivedColumns>
                        <!--
                            Extract the year
                        -->
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER ExtractYear">
                            <Columns>
                                <Column Name="der_Year" DataType="String" Length="2">(IsValidLength) ? SUBSTRING([DrvDOB], 1, 2) : "00"</Column>
                            </Columns>
                        </DerivedColumns>
                        <!--
                            Extract the Month
                        -->
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER ExtractMonth">
                            <Columns>
                                <Column Name="der_Month" DataType="String" Length="2">(IsValidLength) ? SUBSTRING([DrvDOB], 3, 2) : "00"</Column>
                            </Columns>
                        </DerivedColumns>

                        <!--
                            Extract the day
                        -->
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER ExtractDay">
                            <Columns>
                                <Column Name="der_Day" DataType="String" Length="2">(IsValidLength) ? SUBSTRING([DrvDOB], 5, 2) : "00"</Column>
                            </Columns>
                        </DerivedColumns>

                        <!-- 
                            Guess at year based on cutoff date. Assume historical data and not future dated
                            since this is DOB. For supplied value of 2014, 
                            if 14 is seen, it will be 2014
                            if 15 is seen, it will be 1915

                            http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189577(v=sql.105).aspx 
                            A two-digit year that is less than or equal to the last two digits of the cutoff year is 
                            in the same century as the cutoff year. A two-digit year that is greater than the last 
                            two digits of the cutoff year is in the century that precedes the cutoff year. For example, 
                            if two digit year cutoff is 2049 (the default), the two-digit year 49 is interpreted as 2049 
                            and the two-digit year 50 is interpreted as 1950.

                            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024273/convert-a-two-digit-year-to-a-four-digit-year
                            this.TwoDigitYearMax / 100 - (year > this.TwoDigitYearMax % 100 ? 1 : 0)) * 100 + year

                            @[User::TwoDigitYearCutoff]) / 100 - ((Int32) [der_Year] > @[User::TwoDigitYearCutoff]) % 100 ? 1 : 0)) * 100 + (Int32) [der_Year]
                        -->
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER Guess at year">
                            <Columns>
                                <Column DataType="Int32" Name="der_ActualYear"><![CDATA[(@[User::TwoDigitYearCutoff] / 100 - ((DT_I4)der_Year > @[User::TwoDigitYearCutoff] % 100 ? 1 : 0)) * 100 + (DT_I4)der_Year]]></Column>
                            </Columns>
                            <Annotations>
                                <Annotation AnnotationType="Description">This might be overkill, but it sure was fun</Annotation>
                            </Annotations>
                        </DerivedColumns>

                        <!--
                            Put it all together
                        -->
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER Make valid date">
                            <Columns>
                                <Column Name="der_DrvDOB" DataType="Date">(IsValidLength) ? (DT_DATE) ((DT_WSTR, 4) [der_ActualYear] + "-" + [der_Month] + "-" + [der_Day]) : NULL(DT_DATE) </Column>
                            </Columns>
                        </DerivedColumns>

                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER bitbucket">

                        </DerivedColumns>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

### References

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189577(v=sql.105).aspx
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024273/convert-a-two-digit-year-to-a-four-digit-year
- http://web.archive.org/web/20111227015148/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2011/01/12/investigation-can-different-combinations-of-components-effect-dataflow-performance.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot @billinkc. I will go over it. I did sthg like this to handle and it seems like its working it. ([Drv DOB] == "0") || ([Drv DOB] == "101") ? NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) : (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],1,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],3,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],5,2)) . It handles 0 and 101 effectively and as well as output the right format for DOB.

Comment: I have additional data type that I wasn't aware with 7 digits date of birth like 10501101. I am creating a  new post for that. Thank @billinkc

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your statement correct but it appears you have the order of substring wrong (currently you have yy-mm-dd).   Try flipping it around to be mm-dd-yy

```
(DT_DATE)(SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],3,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],1,2))
```

Comment: nope doesn't work.

Comment: what error are you getting? if [Drv DOB] is an integer you will have to add a function to convert it before you substring it I believe.

Comment: this is the error ....[Drv DOB] has string[DT_STR] datatype..........[Derived Column [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  [Derived Column [2]] Error: An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast.
The "Derived Column" failed because error code 0xC0049064 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Derived Column.Inputs[Derived Column Input].Columns[Drv DOB]"

Comment: Have you tried to evaluate each portion of this expression?  For the response I sent you I created multiple variables (int,string,datetime) that I could build the expression and test it vs. trying to get the whole thing right the first time.

Comment: yeah many times.. don't know why I get error. it does seem right.. converting sting to datetime..

Comment: Not sure, as the test I did to come up with that expression worked but my input may have been a different data type than what you have.   Any chance you can alter the processing feeding data to SSIS to have the column calculated in t-sql so you don't have to do through expressions?

Comment: I m sorry I just realize the DOB with values 101 and 0 are invalid. so I have done sthg like this ((LEN([Drv DOB]) < 5) || (LEN([Drv DOB]) > 6)) ? (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)0 : (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING("20" + [Drv DOB],1,2) + SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],3,2) + SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],5,2)).... i don't get any errors but my date format 1899-12-30 00:00:00 when I want is something like this 1951-03-03 00:00:00.000.. The date format 1899-12-30 00:00:00 is what I get for values in the [Drv DOB] column

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74584/multiple-conditions-in-a-derived-column-ssis