# Multiple conditions in a derived column ssis

Tags: ssis, datatypes, type-conversion

Hi I am trying fairly new to SSIS , and my task is to convert dates in string as given below to a datetime.

These are my date of birth  in the source file (string data type):

```
Source date of birth  (String)                             Desired DOB (Date Time) 
•1050101                                                   2005-01-01 00:00:00
•1060101                                                   2006-01-01 00:00:00 
•470324                                                    1947-03-24 00:00:00           
•320209                                                    1932-02-09 00:00:00
•101                                                       NULL
•0                                                         NULL
```

I have this ssis expression,

```
(([Drv DOB] == "0") || ([Drv DOB] == "101") ? NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) : (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],1,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],3,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],5,2)))
```

It handles all dates but except for 7 digit sting date of birth. How can handle such multiple condition. Help much appreciated.

Comment: I changed my expression to the following, but it is not correct. I am trying to solve using nested condition like this, but I have red highlights all over it.........................................................([Drv DOB] == "0") || ([Drv DOB] == "101") ? NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) : (LEN([Drv DOB]) ==6 ? (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],1,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],3,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],5,2) : (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)( SUBSTRING([Drv DOB], 2,2 + "-" + SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],4,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Drv DOB],6,2))

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to handle this in a two step approach this eases maintainability alot.

Have at first a derived column which splits it into the three parts: month, day, year. And afterwards one that converts it to a date.

Another idea to look into would be a conditional split.